# recovery with binlogs?

Tags: mysql, replication, restore, binlog, mysqlbinlog

I would like to know if there is a way that I can restore my databases, I don't have a replication and I would like to migrate my databases without downtime or losing data.
So with binlogs could I do that? I have in my new server already a database but is kinda old, could this be possible.
Thanks in advance

Comment: this is another form of same task - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165914/how-to-restore-several-databases-with-binlogs?noredirect=1#comment320348_165914 , or it separate, new? With small downtime as described in this question - yes it possible todo, but downtime still will be present

Answer (score 0):

if you want to finish your database migration online， replication is necessary.

The common practice for database migration is building replication between your old mysql and new mysql(as slave). When the slave catch the master, switch your business to the mysql(slave).

if you just want to use binlog , you need to lock table during your migrating the database, or you will loss some data.